# Perform Advanced Search - Searching Through Child Relations

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Hello I am trying to build a search in my controller.  These are my **models:**

**Invoice.php**

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Invoice extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    protected $table = 'invoices';

    public function customerDetails() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\CustomerDetails', 'customer_id');
    }

    public function tickets() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Ticket', 'invoice_id');
    }


}
```

**CustomerDetails.php**

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class CustomerDetails extends Model {

    protected $table = 'customer_details';

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User');
    }

    public function invoices() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Invoices', 'customer_id');
    }
}
```

**Ticket.php**

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Ticket extends Model {

    protected $table = 'tickets';

}
```

I have a single search field where the user is allowed to enter a single value:
[image]

The **allowed search parameters** are: **Invoice ID**, **Customer ID**, **First Name**, **Last Name**, **Email**, **Phone**, **Reference ID**, **Purchase Date**

Now what this is supposed to do is go to the invoice table and check if the value entered matches the **invoice_id** or if the value entered matches the **customer_id** or it matches **customer_details->first_name** or **customer_details->last_name** or **customer_details->email** or **customer_details->phone** or **reference_id** or **created_at**

This is what i tried to do in my controller:

```
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function index()
{
    $filter = Input::get('filter');
    $invoices = "";

    if (strlen($filter) > 0)
    {
        $invoices = Invoice::where('id', '=', $filter)
            ->orWhere(function ($query) use ($filter) {
                $query->whereHas('customerDetails', function ($q) use ($filter)  {
                    $q->where('id', '=', $filter)
                    ->orWhere('first_name', '=', $filter)
                    ->orWhere('last_name', '=', $filter);
                });
            })
            ->get();
    }
    else
    {
        $invoices = Invoice::with('customerDetails')
            ->whereRaw('created_at >= CURRENT_DATE')
            ->whereRaw('created_at < CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 1 DAY')
            ->get();
    }

    return [
        'invoices' => $invoices
    ];
}
```

In my above code i haven't added the relation for tickets yet i was just testing against customer_details first.

This is the query laravel generates:

```
select * from `invoices` where `invoices`.`deleted_at` is null and `id` = 'Phil' or ((select count(*) from `customer_details` where `invoices`.`customer_id` = `customer_details`.`id` and `id` = 'Phil' or `first_name` = 'Phil' or `last_name` = 'Phil') >= 1)
```

Based on the data returned i can already tell that that query is wrong because even when the name i entered doesn't exist it still returns some rows.

I would like to know what i am doing wrong and how to fix it and if this way is fast and efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Well i thought through it and finally came up with this, i was trying to figure out how to do it without sing joins but looks like that can't be done so had to do it this way instead:

```
$invoices = Invoice::select('invoices.*')
    ->leftJoin('customer_details', 'customer_details.id', '=', 'invoices.customer_id')
    ->where('invoices.id', '=', $filter)
    ->orWhere('invoices.reference_code', '=', $filter)
    ->orWhereRaw("DATE_FORMAT(invoices.created_at, '%Y-%m-%d') = ?", array($filter))
    ->orWhere('customer_details.id', '=', $filter)
    ->orWhere('customer_details.first_name', '=', $filter)
    ->orWhere('customer_details.last_name', '=', $filter)
    ->orWhere('customer_details.email', '=', $filter)
    ->orWhere('customer_details.phone', '=', $filter)
    ->with('customerDetails')
    ->get();
```